# Spring MVC - Lost data when changing page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm working with a Spring MVC web application. My homepage contain 3 part. 
- The "left menu", used for navigating and changing page.
- The "menu items bar" next to the left menu where i list all items from "Category" table.
- The "body" contain information about products.

All other pages have "left menu" and "menu items bar"

The homepage is successfully loaded after user login and all the items of menu items bar is loaded too. But when i change to another page or searching in homepage, the data of "Menu items bar" is lost.

This problem can be solved if i get the data from each controller corresponding to each page and pass to "menu items bar", but it make a lot of code duplicated.

Is there anyway that i can load data for "menu items bar" only one time and reuse to all other pages?

The "menu items bar" code, info_group.jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <ul>
    <c:forEach var="datagroup" items="${dataGroups}">
        <li class="tree_li">
        <a href="#" onclick="info_grp_tree_on( this ); return false;"><span class="txt">${datagroup.dgName}</span>
        <span class="count">[192]</span></a>
        <div class="sub">
        <ul class="">
        <c:forEach var="datasubgroup" items="${datagroup.dataSubGroups}">
            <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="info_grp_tree_on( this ); return false;"><span class="txt">${datasubgroup.dsgName}
            </span><span class="count">[192]</span></a>
            <div class="list">
            <ul>
            <c:forEach var="keyword" items="${datasubgroup.keywords}">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="info_grp_tree_on( this ); return false;"><span class="ui_shape
                type_a">A</span><span class="txt">${keyword.kwKeyword}</span><span
                class="count">[192]</span></a></li>
            </c:forEach>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And in other page, i called info_group.jsp by:

```
<jsp:include page="../../layout/info_group.jsp" flush="false"/>
```

Comment: You'll need to show code to explain exactly what you mean here. I think you might be looking for a `@ModelAttribute` method.

Comment: I think i found the way to solve this by using Apache Title.

Comment: *Apache tiles may be